# Getting "undefined method 'rule'" on adding a custom rule in reform form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trailblazer, reform

I have just added reform gem and trying to create my first form. I'm writing a custom rule to validate 'email' property. this is my form

```
class StudentForm < Reform::Form
  feature Reform::Form::Dry

  property :first_name, validates: {presence: true}
  property :last_name, validates: {presence: true}
  property :email

  validation name: :email do
    rule(:email) do
        unless /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i.match?(value)
            key.failure('has invalid format')
        end
    end
  end
end
```

I get this when I do StudentForm.new

```
undefined method `rule' for #<Reform::Form::ActiveModel::Validations::Group:0x00007f63d014c068 @validations=#<Class:0x00007f63d013ff70>> (NoMethodError)
```

I have also created an initializer which makes sure reform uses Dry validation instead of active model, as recommended in the docs

```
require "reform/form/dry"
Reform::Form.class_eval do
  feature Reform::Form::Dry
end
```

I think it is still using active model, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I did what the docs said.

Comment: Get rid of the email regex validation. You're actually just doing your users a disservice by blocking perfectly legit email adresses like `jörgen.von.klückensjäger!foo+stopspammingme@exämple.com`. https://www.netmeister.org/blog/email.html

Comment: 99% emails are covered with [this regex](https://emailregex.com/#crayon-5dcf0d9dc15ec916764848)It's up to you use it or no 

Comment: Didn't help with the actual issue but I appreciate your comment, I just copied the regex from somewhere

Comment: [Docs](https://trailblazer.to/2.1/docs/reform.html#reform-rails-reform-rails) suggest a different way to indicate you want to use dry validations.

Comment: I was on that page whole day and didn't see that line, I followed reform-rails github repo's instruction, this line was not mentioned there. Will check if this helps @smathy

Comment: This worked @smathy, can you make an answer so I can accept that. thanks for the help.

Comment: Nice, glad to hear. I added the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs](https://trailblazer.to/2.1/docs/reform.html#reform-rails-reform-rails) say you should be doing this to indicate you want to use dry validations:

```rb
Rails.application.config.reform.validations = :dry
```